# Why do we even need forwardRef in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-forwardref

I can find multiple examples/docs explaining how we can pass a ref to function component using `forwardRef` but never found any explanation **WHY** we use `forwardRef` at all.

[Here's my codepen to demonstrate my point.](https://codepen.io/milfhunter/pen/jOaBoNv)

In both cases, clicking the "focus" button next to the input will focus the input to left. The first input utilizes `forwardRef` while the second doesn't.

Here's the source code for SEO:

```
import * as React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import * as ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";

const WithForwardRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <input type="text" placeholder="WithForwardRef" ref={ref} />;
});

const WithoutForwardRef = ({ myRef }) => {
  return <input type="text" placeholder="WithoutForwardRef" ref={myRef} />;
}

function App() {

  const ref1 = React.useRef();
  const ref2 = React.useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <WithForwardRef ref={ref1} />
        <button onClick={() => ref1.current.focus()}>focus</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div>
        <WithoutForwardRef myRef={ref2} />
        <button onClick={() => ref2.current.focus()}>focus</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("mainApp"));
```

Comment: You demonstrated why: `ref` isn't a prop that's passed to your component, it's managed by React. If you want to stick with React's API and offer `ref` for a custom component, `forwardRef` is the way. It helps when you don't have full control over the API, like an HOC.

Comment: Both comments, your HOC advice and the related question were super helpful for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy it helped! :)